# remove duplicates from string having string char more than one

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, data-cleaning

Thanks for helping, I am trying to remove duplicate words from add column in pract_df dataframe, The output not as expected.The udf also attached

```
scala> pract_df.withColumn("add1", cleanNamePattern(col("add"))).show(false)
    +--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
    |add                                         |add1                                        |
    +--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
    |505152 SANAGONDA ODELA PEDDAPALLI 9985250499|505152 SANAGONDA ODELA PEDDAPALLI 9985250499|
    | kurnool nannuru kurnool                    | KURNOOL NANNURU                            |
    |R R district                                |R DISTRICT                                  |
    |J J nagara J J colonty                      |J NAGARA COLONTY                            |
    |sunil reddy reddy                           |SUNIL REDDY                                 |
    |ramesh reddy sunil reddy                    |RAMESH REDDY SUNIL                          |
    +--------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

the below is the udf applied for removing duplicates in add column, add1 is the result after applying the udf.

```
val cleanNamePattern1 = udf((data: String) => {
      if (data == null) ""
      else if (data.isEmpty) ""
      else if(data.toLowerCase().contains("reddy","[a-zA-Z]{1} [a-zA-Z]{1}")) data
      else  {
        var result: String = ""
        for (s <- data.toLowerCase.replaceAll(" {1,}"," ").split(" ").toArray.distinct.mkString(" ")) {
          result += ""+s
        }
        result.trim
      }
      data.toLowerCase.replaceAll(" {1,}"," ").split(" ").toArray.distinct.mkString(" ")
        .toUpperCase()
    })
```

My expected iutput is

```
505152 SANAGONDA ODELA PEDDAPALLI 9985250499
 KURNOOL NANNURU                            
R R DISTRICT                        
J J NAGARA COLONTY   
SUNIL REDDY                                                           
RAMESH REDDY SUNIL
```

I want to consider string charcter having more than one.

Comment: What is the problem then ?

Comment: I want to take only string character more than one:example R R output should be same,but output is showing only R.

Comment: can u make a better title pls

Comment: Is this possible as input?  JJ JJ nagara J J colonty   ? What would the output be? I assume the col is just a string.

Comment: for example having data like `R R DISTRICT KURNOOL KURNOOL`, I want output as `R R DISTRICT KURNOOL`.; but while applying this `rdd.split(" ").distinct.mkString(" ")` showing output as `res9: String = J COLONY KURNOOL`

Comment: the question is unclear imo

Comment: I have data like `kurnool kurnool nagar`, from this data i want to remove `kurnool` and result be `kurnool nagar`, means removing duplicate string in data.

Comment: Yes, but I am not a complete buffoon, what would this amount to? JJ JJ nagara J J colonty .  Or is this not possible?